SwiftUI with localized views in packages won't show previews
I have created this localized SwiftUI Test-Project, and I set up this project with a localization package and 2 packages with different views, one using the other one.
I want to show TheParentView, which shows TheChildView, imagine these for a bigger project with several views, in any depth of subviews, separated in packages.
Now Xcode's XCPreview isn't able to show the preview for the Child and tends to crash after some time, but it still can for the Parent, even though the code is practically the same.
In the project View, the text is localized and shown totally fine.
In TheParentView package, the view shows the keys instead of the localized strings, that's fine, due to XCPreview still having issues with fetching the default locale in situations like this.
In TheChildView package, the view can't be presented and XCPreview crashes after some time.
The exception type is a SIGTRAP that could practically come from anywhere, the first report lines aren't showing anything useful, just referring to a "first closure on launch".
XCPreview Exception Type: EXC_BREAKPOINT (SIGTRAP)

I can still build and run the project fine on simulator and device, but without the previews, the development process slows down quite a bit.
Other questions refer to breakpoints due to the exception type, but I don't have any in the project.
I expect XCPreview to be able to at least show TheChildView like TheParentView with the localization keys or other placeholders handed in the #Preview of the code.
-----Update-----
I change the String package type to .dynamic, and now at least both View-Packages show the same error, more like I expected, but that error shows
     LinkDylibError: Failed to build TheParentView.swift

Linking failed: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Undefined symbols for architecture arm64:
  "Strings.L.first.unsafeMutableAddressor : SwiftUI.LocalizedStringKey", referenced from:
      closure #1 @Swift.MainActor () -> SwiftUI.View in static TheParentView_PreviewReplacement_TheParentView_1.$s033TheParentView_PreviewReplacement_abC2_133_755AF9EAB51BED29A3BA74CCC1C408E5Ll0D0fMf_15PreviewRegistryfMu_.makePreview() throws -> DeveloperToolsSupport.Preview in TheParentView.1.preview-thunk.o
  "Strings.L.second.unsafeMutableAddressor : SwiftUI.LocalizedStringKey", referenced from:
      closure #1 () -> SwiftUI.TupleView<(SwiftUI.Button<SwiftUI.Label<SwiftUI.Text, SwiftUI.EmptyView>>, TheChildView.TheChildView)> in (extension in TheParentView_PreviewReplacement_TheParentView_1):TheParentView.TheParentView.(__preview__body in _755AF9EAB51BED29A3BA74CCC1C408E5).getter : some in TheParentView.1.preview-thunk.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture arm64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

and I don't really understand the problem here, I don't see any architecture issues anywhere and if this comes from an linker error, I wouldn't expect the project to build and run seamlessly on simulator and device.

No longer occurs with Xcode 16
After the WWDC Apple started sharing the new beta of Xcode 16, and they completely changed the XCPreview Build process, to be clear- they dropped it and are using the simulator build for the preview and like magic, the issue is no more!
